# Is there any command-line image/PDF/PPT (powerpoint) viewer that supports transitions?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, presentation

I was looking for some viewers that can handle displaying both pictures and PDFs (ideally, PPTs, but I reckon that's asking too much), with transitions (fade in, fade out, etc).

On top of that, I needed a CLI interface (not GUI).

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** Ideally I was looking for a single viewer, but if it can't be done then what are the alternatives? Right now, I'm thinking about using [fbi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/fbi.1.html) for everything (that would include extracting each slide as an image). I don't really like this solution, especially because fbi doesn't really support transitions between each photo (a simple fade-in would suffice).

**Edit2:** I wanted to make a script that used these viewers, that's why I wanted to avoid GUIs.

Comment: Pictures, PDFs and PPTs have very different viewers. Would it be okay, if there would be several applications for each? How important is the CLI? Why is it important? - Please edit your question and add the information.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux

Comment: Just added more information

Comment: @Hal you've still not answered a key question: How important is the CLI interface, and why?  As it currently stands, the only answers you're going to get are for GUI things, not CLI, because most, if not all, of any recommendations are going to be GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no truly CLI interface to view PDFs, Pictures, or PPT presentations, those all require graphical interfaces to display transitions and pictures.

While I'm fairly certain that text within a PDF or a PPT can probably be displayed after some conversion to other formats, there is no CLI interface which I know of that can actually do what you're asking for.

I am also certain there is no one all-inclusive viewer for this, and you'll have to use multiple tools if you want the GUI.

Comment: I've edited my question; what about multiple viewers?

Comment: @Hal before asking me to revise my answer, answer all the questions MadMike and myself posed to you in the comments to your question.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Hal there are still no CLI viewers for your purposes.  CLI doesn't permit the viewing of pictures, powerpoint presentations, or PDFs without converting to other formats, and even then, it will only be able to display text because it can't display pictures.  Your only options are to use GUI programs.

Comment: I just need to be able to call it from the terminal without getting a GUI in the way (splashscreens, menus, etc), not display the picture inside the terminal itself. FBI does this well, it's just too bad that it doesn't support animations between each picture.

Comment: There is no CLI-controlled system for that, Hal.  My answer here still stands, to my knowledge, there are no such software you're looking for.